# Images for multitouch in android

Tags: android

How to place a game piece in game board for every touch in android? I am unable to get multi images for every touch. Can anyone please give me code for these types of example?

Comment: We don't write code for you here-  we help you to code.  But if you're looking to find how to write multitouch code, look at MotionEvent and the POINTER_DOWN and POINTER_UP actions.

Comment: freelancer.com is the place for you, judging from other questions. You need to show what you have done, relevant code and any unexpected outputs or errors. We won't write your code for you, but freelancer will for a fair price!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree with the other comment that says that we will not give you code, however, I will help you out a little because I know how it feels to be completely lost on something. :)

Here is the 'commented' version of what you need to do.

I would actually take the easy way out for this and do this in an extremely cheap method that others will probably laugh at and call stupid, but I think works for this situation.

First display the checkerboard image on an XML file using the Image View. You will need to read up on how to actually do this.

I would then put multiple image views that cover each "check", as looking as their are a minimal amount of boxes in the checkerboard. You can actually use a relative layout to do this so that the checkerboard and its assets spread out over the entire scene.

After creating the image views and creating the assets, you can create Java logic that is able to put specific assets into specific image views. Remember, this is a small scale solution that will work for someone who I assume is not very experienced in Android.

You can put hidden buttons in each of the boxes in the checkerboard so that you will be able to get input on which boxes were touched, and will have full control on what what boxes get covered with your pictures.

This is the first Stack Overflow question I have answered, so I am doing my best. I don't have my Android compiler in front of me right now, so I am not able to write as good of an explanation. If you have any questions, go ahead and ask me in the comments and I will help you out.

AeroVTP